# How to get notification if System Preferences Default Sound changed

Tags: macos, cocoa, notifications, core-audio

This is fairly simple (I think).  I'm simply wanting to get a notification in my application whenever a user changes the default sound input or sound output device in System Preferences - Sound.  I'll be darned if I'm able to dig it out of the Apple docs, however.

As a side note, this is for OSX, not IOS.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Try to use search (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747016/how-do-i-register-for-a-notification-for-then-the-sound-volume-changes)

Comment: That doesn't work when the default sound input or output device selection changes.  Great for detecting volume levels, not great for detecting device selection changes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set up an `AudioObjectPropertyAddress` for the default output device:

```
AudioObjectPropertyAddress outputDeviceAddress = {
    kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice,
    kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
    kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster
};
```

Then, use `AudioObjectAddPropertyListener` to register a listener for changes in the default device:

```
AudioObjectAddPropertyListener(kAudioObjectSystemObject, 
                                 &outputDeviceAddress,
                                 &callbackFunction, nil);
```

The callback function looks like this:

```
OSStatus callbackFunction(AudioObjectID inObjectID, 
                            UInt32 inNumberAddresses,
                            const AudioObjectPropertyAddress inAddresses[],             
                            void *inClientData)
```

As a side note, you should also use `AudioObjectPropertyAddress` to tell the HAL to manage its own thread for notifications. You do this by setting the run loop selector to NULL. I actually perform this step before setting up the output device listener.

```
AudioObjectPropertyAddress runLoopAddress = {
    kAudioHardwarePropertyRunLoop, 
    kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
    kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster
};

CFRunLoopRef runLoop = NULL;
UInt32 size = sizeof(CFRunLoopRef);
AudioObjectSetPropertyData(kAudioObjectSystemObject, 
                            &runLoopAddress, 0, NULL, size, &runLoop);
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's how to do it in Swift:

1. Register for notifications by adding a listener block, for example when a View Controller loads its view. The `addListenerBlock` function simplifies adding property listener blocks. Swift allows parameters to be variables, which is very convenient for the `forPropertyAddress` parameter. When calling `addListenerBlock`, the property address parameters are just plugged in.

   ```
   import Cocoa
   import CoreAudio

   class ViewController: NSViewController {

      // Utility function to simplify adding listener blocks:
      func addListenerBlock( listenerBlock: AudioObjectPropertyListenerBlock, onAudioObjectID: AudioObjectID, var forPropertyAddress: AudioObjectPropertyAddress) {
         if (kAudioHardwareNoError != AudioObjectAddPropertyListenerBlock(onAudioObjectID, &forPropertyAddress, nil, listenerBlock)) {
             print("Error calling: AudioObjectAddPropertyListenerBlock") }
      }


      override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad()

         addListenerBlock(audioObjectPropertyListenerBlock, 
            onAudioObjectID: AudioObjectID(bitPattern: kAudioObjectSystemObject),
            forPropertyAddress: AudioObjectPropertyAddress(
               mSelector: kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice,
               mScope: kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
               mElement: kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster))
      }

   ...
   ```
2. Provide a listener block function to receive the notifications. You're given an array that could potentially have more than one property address, so loop through and look for the one you want:

   ```
      func audioObjectPropertyListenerBlock (numberAddresses: UInt32, addresses: UnsafePointer<AudioObjectPropertyAddress>) {

         var index: UInt32 = 0
         while index < numberAddresses {
             let address: AudioObjectPropertyAddress = addresses[0]
             switch address.mSelector {
             case kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice:

                 let deviceID = getDefaultAudioOutputDevice()
                 print("kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice: \(deviceID)")

             default:

                 print("We didn't expect this!")

             }
             index += 1
        }

        // Utility function to get default audio output device:
        func getDefaultAudioOutputDevice () -> AudioObjectID {

            var devicePropertyAddress = AudioObjectPropertyAddress(mSelector: kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice, mScope: kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal, mElement: kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster)
            var deviceID: AudioObjectID = 0
            var dataSize = UInt32(truncatingBitPattern: sizeof(AudioDeviceID))
            let systemObjectID = AudioObjectID(bitPattern: kAudioObjectSystemObject)
            if (kAudioHardwareNoError != AudioObjectGetPropertyData(systemObjectID, &devicePropertyAddress, 0, nil, &dataSize, &deviceID)) { return 0 }
            return deviceID
        }

   }
   ```

Of course, you can simply add more `cases` to the `switch` statement if you want to monitor other audio device properties. Call `addListenerBlock` to add whatever devices and property addresses you're interested in.

Comment: On the line `let address: AudioObjectPropertyAddress = addresses[0]` did you mean to put `index` instead of `0`?